# JQuery-UI draggable item become undraggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I have 2 divs: `leftDiv` and `mainDiv`. `leftDiv` contains some list elements which are draggable and droppable into `mainDiv`. I want to make these dropped items draggable inside the `mainDiv` as well, but after the first drag inside this div, items become non draggable. How can I fix this? Here is my jQuery code:

```
$('#output li').draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: 'invalid'
});
$('#mainDiv').droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        if(ui.draggable.hasClass('foo')){
            $(ui.helper).remove();
            $(this).append(ui.draggable.draggable());
        }
        else {
            var item = $('<div class="foo">').append(ui.draggable.text());
            item.draggable();
            $(this).append(item);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Please create a snippet for us to test out, its kinda hard to guess the reason from what information we have

Comment: I think you need to have `$("#mainDiv li').draggable({...})` if you want to be able to drag files from `mainDiv`

Comment: can you tell me what is foo div contain and share you full code or share html

Comment: VTodorov, your answer is correct. That was so simple :D If you write it as an answer I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix it like this:

```
$('#mainDiv').droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        if(ui.draggable.hasClass('foo')){
            //$(ui.helper).remove();
            var draggedItem = ui.draggable.draggable();            
            $(this).append(draggedItem);
            draggedItem.draggable();
        }
        else {
            var item = $('<div class="foo">').append(ui.draggable.text());
            item.draggable();
            $(this).append(item);
        }
    }
});
```

[**Online Demo (fiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/pqgcea4r/1/)

Comment: @VaxoBasilidze Please up-vote my answer for knowing and helping other people that it helps you because some people only see the up-voted answers.